# Simple commands not found bash (#!/usr/bin/expect)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, expect

I've recently started using bash to automate a windows rescue disk with `chntpw`. I'm trying to set up the program to use the `expect` command to listen for certain `chntpw` dialog questions and input the right answers without any user input. For some reason after setting up the bash script to use `#!/usr/bin/expect` rather than `#!/bin/bash` then many standard terminal commands are no longer understood.

I'm running the script by typing this into terminal:

```
user@kali:~/Desktop/projects/breezee$ bash breezee1.sh
```

The terminal output is as follows:

```
BREEZEE 1.0
Welcome to BREEZEE
breezee1.sh: line 9: fdisk: command not found
[Select] /dev/:
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
clear
echo "BREEZEE 1.0"
echo "Welcome to BREEZEE"

fdisk -l 
#list partitions
echo -n "[Select] /dev/:"
#ask user to choose primary windows partition
read sda
clear

echo /dev/$sda selected

umount /dev/$sda
sudo ntfsfix /dev/$sda
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/$sda /mnt/
cd /mnt/Windows/System32/config

clear
chntpw -l SAM #list accounts on windows partition
chntpw -u Administrator SAM
#now supply chntpw with values to run the password clear (this answers the prompts)

expect '> ' 
send '1\r'
expect '> '
send '2\r'
expect '> '
send '3\r'
expect ': '
send 'y\r'
expect '> '
send 'q\r'
expect ': '
send 'y\r'

clear
echo "Operation Successfull!"
chntpw -l SAM #list accounts on windows partition
```

In short, I'm trying to use standard bash/terminal commands alongside the `expect` commands. I'm probably going about this all wrong, so please correct me as I've been troubleshooting this for about three days and haven't gotten far :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify the application that should run your script, you can only use the scripting language that application will understand.

Clearly, Expect is not bash, and does not understand bash commands.

i suggest you separate those two scripts. Write the first part for `!#/bin/bash`, the second for Expect. Make the first script invoke the second script and redirect it to chntpw.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. Being new to bash I just assumed `!#/usr/bin/expect` was an alternative bash interpreter with expect support included. Clearly I was wrong and that's where my confusion stemmed from. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait, so I just changed the interpreter to `!#/bin/bash` and I'm still getting the `fdisk: command not found` issue? **Update:** Adding `sudo` fixed it.

Comment: @pattyd: Also, running the script with e.g. `bash breezee1.sh` will run it as a bash script no matter what the shebang (`#!`) line says. In general, you should make scripts executable (e.g. `chmod +x breezee1.sh`) and then run them with something like `./breezee1.sh` (which lets the shebang control how it's run).

Comment: @pattyd; Do make sure that you have #! and not !# before the /bin/bash.  I always have to remind myself by muttering "shebang" for 'hash, exclamation point'.

Answer (score 3):

`expect` uses [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) not bash. So you can write your script in TCL when you use `#!/usr/bin/expect`.

For example, `echo "BREEZEE 1.0"` should be written as:

```
puts "BREEZEE 1.0"
```

And you should use `exp_send` instead of `send`.

From [expect manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

> **exp_send** is an alias for **send**. If you are using Expectk or some other variant of Expect in the Tk environment, **send** is defined by Tk for an entirely different purpose. **exp_send is provided for compatibility between environments**. Similar aliases are provided for other Expect's other **send** commands.